# How do aggregate function on two cells of a record in a database table and show its result in another table in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `Product` and `SellingIncome` as shown in the screenshot below, and I need in the `SellingIncome` table to set for the `SellingIncome` column to insert automatically the multiplication of columns `ProductPrice` and `SellingCount` in the `Product` table (I mean ==>

```
SellingIncome.SellingIncome = Product.ProductPrice * Product.SellingCount
```

[image]

How can solve this problem? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: If (as it looks) this is the sole purpose of the table SellingIncome then don't do it. Don't even bother with this table. All you need is the table Product and this query: `SELECT *, ProductPrice * SellingCount AS SellingIncome FROM Product`.

Comment: @forpas: I completely agree with forpas. The `sellingincome` table doesn't seem to make sense. Drop it and only use the product table.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about the "sellingincome" table.  You can just use a computed column in `product`:

```
alter table product add column sellingincome as
    (productprice * sellingcount);
```

Using a computed column means that `sellingincome` is always up-to-date.

Comment: Thank you. That is working, but I need "sellingincome" table to insert the answer of (productprice * sellingcount) in it. Please help!